# discord.js v14 private voice channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

Where could I be wrong? I have been trying to get it working for several hours, but to no avail, the code does not work. Can anyone help with this?

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate",(oldState,newState)=>{
    var categoryid = "1081228230321087824";
    var channelid = "103284326182943242";
    
    if(newState.channel?.id == channelid){
       newState.guild.channels.create(`${newState.member.user.username}'s channel`,{
            name: "voice-${user.username}",
            type: ChannelType.GuildText,
            parent: categoryid,
            permissionOverwrites:[{
                id: newState.member.id,
                allow: ["MANAGE_CHANNELS"]
            },{
                id: newState.guild.id,
                deny:["MANAGE_CHANNELS"]
            }] 
        }).then(channel=>{
            newState.setChannel(channel)
            channel.createInvite({
                maxAge:0,
                maxUses:0
            })
        })
    } 
    if(oldState.channel?.id != channelid && oldState.channel?.parent?.id == categoryid && !oldState.channel?.members.size) oldState.channel.delete();
})
```

Nothing happens at startup, even errors in the logs do not appear.

Comment: _"Nothing happens at startup"_ What do you expect to happen?

Comment: When connecting to a voice channel, a new one will be created, then I will be transferred there

Comment: I see. What is `newState`? It's not defined in your code. and should definitely throw an error. If it doesn't throw an error it's because `channelid` is incorrect and you never reach what's inside that `if` statement. Another thing is that the `voiceStateUpdate` event takes `VoiceState`s as parameters so `oldUser` and `newUser` are not the best names for these and probably that's why you mixed things up.

Comment: Yes, I did not notice something. Changed to oldState and newState, but it didn't help

Comment: You'll still need to do some basic debugging. Have you tried to log `newState.channel.id` and check if your `channelid` is correct?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was easy and simple, I made a mistake in writing voiceStateUpdate and calling it, I also had a mistake in writing flags.

```
const newChannel = newState.guild.channels.create({
name: `${newState.member.user.username}'s Channel`,
type: ChannelType.GuildVoice,
parent: newState.channel.parent,
topic: channelid,
permissionOverwrites:[{
      id: newState.member.id,
      allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels]
},{
      id: newState.guild.id,
      deny:[PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageChannels]
}]
```